# How to pull ids from array of hashes on ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

Given:

```
data = [
  {"id"=>nil, "votable_id"=>1150, "user_ids"=>"1120,1119,1118,1117,1116,1115,1114,1113,1112,1111,1110,1109,1108,1107"},
  {"id"=>nil, "votable_id"=>1151, "user_ids"=>"1120,1119,1118,1117,1116,1115,1114,1113,1112,1111,1110,1109,1108,1107"}
]
```

I wish to return an array of all unique representations of integers in the strings `g["user_ids"]`, taken over all hashes `g` that are elements of `data`; namely,

```
["1120", "1119", "1118", "1117", "1116", "1115", "1114",
 "1113", "1112", "1111", "1110", "1109", "1108", "1107"]
```

Comment: `map` and `uniq` is enough `x.map { |y| y['user_ids'] }.uniq`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I think you missed that it is a string that contains ids

Comment: Add a `.split(',')`.

Comment: It gives me an array of array then i will have to use flatten. Is there any other way ?

Comment: `users.flat_map { |user| user['user_ids'].split(',') }.uniq`

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. If this is Rails parameter related, the better option is to make sure incoming parameters are already an array format. Have a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions

Comment: There is a SO rule that for hashes used in examples, values can be no longer than 0.5 kms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the unique ids:

```
unique_ids = data.flat_map { |d| d['user_ids'].split(',') }.uniq
```

1. [`Enumerable#flat_map`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable:flat_map) walks through the Array and concatenate
   the results provided in the code block.
2. [`String#split`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:split) divides the string by the delimiter
   into an Array.
3. [`Array#uniq`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:uniq) removes the duplicates.

Comment: Don't just toss out code, explain it and why your answer is the correct one. The goal is to educate in addition to solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Rails, try this:

```
data.pluck('user_ids').join(',').split(',').uniq
```

If you don't use Rails:

```
data.map{ |d| d.dig('user_ids') }.join(',').split(',').uniq
```

Result:

```
#=> [
#     "1120", "1119", "1118", "1117", "1116", "1115", "1114",
#     "1113", "1112", "1111", "1110", "1109", "1108", "1107"
#   ]
```

Comment: Explain why this is useful. Educate, don't just toss out code.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.reduce('') { |s,h| s + h['user_ids'] + ',' }.scan(/\d+/).uniq
  #=> ["1120", "1119", "1118", "1117", "1116", "1115", "1114", "1113",
  #    "1112", "1111", "1110", "1109", "1108", "1107"]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
str = data.reduce('') { |s,h| s + h['user_ids'] + ',' }
  => "1120,1119,...1107,1120,1119,...1107," 
arr = str.scan(/\d+/)
  #=> ["1120", "1119", "1118", "1117", "1116", "1115", "1114", "1113",
  #    "1112", "1111", "1110", "1109", "1108", "1107", "1120", "1119",
  #    "1118", "1117", "1116", "1115", "1114", "1113", "1112", "1111",
  #    "1110", "1109", "1108", "1107"]
arr.uniq
  #=> ["1120", "1119", "1118", "1117", "1116", "1115", "1114", "1113",
  #    "1112", "1111", "1110", "1109", "1108", "1107"]
```

A problem with this approach is that the intermediate array `arr` can be quite large if `data` contains many elements (hashes) and for each element `h`, `h['user_ids'].split(',')` contains many elements. One way around that is to build a set, which of course contains unique elements, and then convert that set to an array at the end.

```
require 'set'

data.each_with_object(Set.new) { |h,set|
  h["user_ids"].split(',').each { |s| set << s } }.to_a
  #=> ["1120", "1119", "1118", "1117", "1116", "1115", "1114",
  #    "1113", "1112", "1111", "1110", "1109", "1108", "1107"]
```

See [Set::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-c-new), [Set#<<](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) and [Set#to_a](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-to_a).

Note that the array returned here contains the same elements as the array returned earlier, but in a different order. I assume that is no import.

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer